# how to install ipv4 via a cmd windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, ipv4

I need to script a way to install IPV4 on windows xp the reason is i have many pc with a corrupt win sock registry so the fix Microsoft has is to delete the reg keys hklm/system/currentcontolset/services/winsock and winsock2 and then to run a netsch ip reset which creates the winsock2 part of the registry then the part i need to script is go to network adapter properties goto tcpip and install a new protocol and select tcp/ip and install it which uses the file c:\windows\inf\nettcpip.inf and then this  creates the winsock part is there a way to script this part?? i have looked and cant find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a way so did it with registry keys